# Algorithm for real time Coordinate smoothing

Tags: algorithms, robotics

So I get new Coordinates every 10ms even with RTK fixed precision, they jump between 1-3cm. The Coordinates are the current Position of my Vehicle

I have a Vehicle using these Coordinates to follow a drawn Path.

Now as the Coordinates Jump, the Vehicle tries to follow them and is driving in curves instead of a straight line sometimes more sometimes less depending on how sensitive the steering is.

My question now is, what Algorithm is capable of "smoothing" incoming Coordinates in real-time to avoid the jumping around?

Kalman-Filter / Douglas-Peucker or something else?

Does a prediction of the next current position help? -- Maybe with the help of an IMU?

Answer (score 1):

A Kalman filter is a reasonable choice for this.  It is useful for tracking the movement of an object, as it can be used with a model for the physics of the movement of an object.

Comment: This. In fact, the IMU would be an excellent approach, as the two samples could correct each other using a Kalman filter.